# OpenSSL pkcs12 Export chained CA Certs separately

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a cert chain that looks like this:

- Global CA

  - Intermediate CA

    - MyCert

I am using openssl.exe to create .cer files from MyCert.pfx, and I want the generated cert to contain the client cert first, followed by the Intermediate CA cert. The end result should look something like this:

```
Bag Attributes
  <mycert attributes>

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  <mycert data>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  

Bag Attributes
  <intermediate ca attributes>

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  <intermediate ca data>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I can get the first cert by running

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MyCert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -password pass:mypassword -out mycert.cer
```

And I can run the command to get the CA certs in the chain like this

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MyCert.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -password pass:mypassword -out cacert.cer
```

But this generates a file with both the Global CA and the Intermediate CA certs.

Is there a way to specify only the Intermediate CA by CN or something?

I can get the content out of the file but was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I opted for the gross way... Here it is.

```powershell
# Generate the client cert
&"$opensslPath\openssl.exe" pkcs12 -in "$($filepathforCert).pfx" -clcerts -nokeys -out "$($filepathforCert)-fullchain.crt" -password pass:$certPassword

# Generate the CA certs in the chain
&"$opensslPath\openssl.exe" pkcs12 -in "$($filepathforCert).pfx" -cacerts -nokeys -out "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -password pass:$certPassword


# Combine certs
# The common name for the intermediate CA should be the same until 2031
$intermediateCaCn = "CN = DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1"
$certBeginToken = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
$certEndToken = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

$intermediateCACertStart = (Select-String -Pattern $intermediateCaCn -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -SimpleMatch | select-object -First 1).LineNumber
$firstCertStart = (Select-String -Pattern $certBeginToken -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -SimpleMatch | select-object -First 1).LineNumber

$intermediateStartLine = 0
$intermediateEndLine = 0

# The beginning of the cert will always start after the CN
if($intermediateCACertStart -gt $firstCertStart)
{
    $intermediateStartLine = (Select-String -Pattern $certBeginToken -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -SimpleMatch | select-object -Last 1).LineNumber
    $intermediateEndLine = (Select-String -Pattern $certEndToken -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -SimpleMatch | select-object -Last 1).LineNumber
}
else
{
    $intermediateStartLine = $firstCertStart
    $intermediateEndLine = (Select-String -Pattern $certEndToken -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt" -SimpleMatch | select-object -First 1).LineNumber
}

# size of the cert, including the delimiters
$lineCount = ($intermediateEndLine - $intermediateStartLine)

$certContent = (Get-Content -Path "$($filepathforCACert).crt"| Select-Object -Skip ($intermediateStartLine - 1) -First ($lineCount +1))

Add-Content -Path "$($filepathforCert)-fullchain.crt" -Value $certContent
```